# How to normalise a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, normalize

I have a 3D numpy array of a user defined length and i don't know how to normalise it. The usual packages such as numpy and scipy only accept 2D arrays so i'm a bit stumped. The code for my numpy array can be seen below.
`Matrix=np.zeros((a,a,a))`
Where a is a user define value

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to normalize an array with all zeros !

```py
A = np.random.randn(2, 2, 2)
# A = np.zeros((2, 2, 2))
Amax = np.max(A)
Amin = np.min(A)
Range = Amax - Amin
Anrm = ((A - Amin)/Range - 0.5) * 2
```

Try using the above code, also refer the MatLab code https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/364721-how-to-normalize-3d-array-with-negative-and-positive-values-to-values-between-1-and-1

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, i forgot to say that the zeros are going to be replaced by different values. i just thought to give that example to give an idea of the matrix i was dealing with. Also, thank you, i will give this a go